# Display alert on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display a message when the user presses any key in the search bar. After several tries, I am unable to do it.

```
<form method="get" >
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn" >
    <input name="q" type="text" id="search" size="32" maxlength="128" class="txt" >
</form>
```

Following is my JavaScript:

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {                                                   // function starts when a key is entered in the search bar
  window.alert("Handler for .keyup() called.");     
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try wrapping your code in a `$(document).ready` to make sure the dom is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function() {                                                   // function starts when a key is entered in the search bar
      window.alert("Handler for .keyup() called.");     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On ready pls

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#search").keyup(function() {                                                   //             

   //function starts when a key is entered in the search bar
   window.alert("Handler for .keyup() called.");     
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the console for JS errors and just `alert("Handler for .keyup() called.");` should do the trick for you. Plus try adding `$(document).ready(function(){});` in your code **or** put your code at the end of your page. Make sure input fields exists with the id search.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function() {                     
      window.alert("Handler for .keyup() called.");     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

place your code in document ready callback..
it is not showing alert because of that only.

```
$(function(){
   $("#search").keyup(function() {            
   //function starts when a key is entered in the search bar
     window.alert("Handler for .keyup() called.");     
    });
});
```